# Generating a list with REST to produce Json response

Tags: java, json, rest

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;    
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;



/** Example resource class hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
 */
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {
    
    /** Method processing HTTP GET requests, producing "text/plain" MIME media
     * type.
     * @return String that will be send back as a response of type "text/plain".
     */
    @Produces("application/json")
    @GET 
    public JsonArray datas() {
        return Json.createArrayBuilder().
                add(data(1,"Titanic",1998,"Dramatic")).
                add(data(2,"Transformers 1",2004,"Action")).
                add(data(3,"Fast and Furious",2007,"Action")).
                build();
    }
    
    public JsonObject data(int id, String title, int year, String type) {
        return Json.createObjectBuilder().
                add("id",id).
                add("title",title).
                add("year",year).
                add("type",type).
                build();
    }
}
```

So here is my Java class where I make the code.
All dependencies have been added.
My problem is with the return.
Instead of showing me the list of the 3 films that I put. I have this return there (SEE THE PICTURE)
[image: RETURN]

Someone can help me ? Thank you

Comment: Can you rephrase? There doesn't seem to be a clear question here.

Comment: Sorry.
My question is: Why in the browser it does not show me the 3 elements that I have added to my Arraylist

Comment: Have a look at this one, might help https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html

Comment: What is your environment?  I took your exact code and ran it under Wildfly 20 and it works fine.

Comment: @Sunil Thank you for your reply. I have already looked at the documentation and think this part of the code is correct. I don't understand where the error came from.

Comment: @stdunbar I'm working with eclipse and my browser is chrome

Comment: But what is your application server?  Tomcat, Wildfly, etc?

Comment: Tomcat 7 sorry @stdunbar

Comment: try to change the return type of `datas()` to just `String` and after the `build()` method call, add `.toString()`

Comment: @stdunbar I tried with Wildfly 20 and it's the same for me.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi 
I just tried your proposal, it works it displays what I want but suddenly it's not a Json object anymore?

Comment: what do you mean with `it's not a Json object anymore`? it should display an array of objects containing movies information.